# Sharing controls in ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a grid that I want to share in several places, the grid has several controls (textboxes, labels, textblocks and buttons). I placed it in my ResourceDictionary like so:

```
<Grid Background="LightGray" x:Key="gridShare">
   <!-- other controls here -->
</Grid>
```

But when I use it in more than one place I get an exception saying:

"Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first."

Which makes sense, so I'm wondering if there's any other way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is create a custom control with this as a template, then use an instance of this custom control instead of the Grid itself.  Alternately create a UserControl and use instances of it.

Comment: Ha! I've done this before! I guess I'm blocked of working too much. Worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to do (present the exact same composite control in multiple places), you can put the grid in a `ControlTemplate` and apply it to `ContentControl`s:

In the ResourceDictionary:

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="frequentlyUsedTemplate">
  <Grid>
    [...]
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In a UserControl:

```xml
<ContentControl Content="[...]" Template="{StaticResource frequentlyUsedTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: Even though I like your solution very much, in my current situation the other one is simpler. Thank you for the suggestion!